# Catch fails on simple example

Tags: c++, c++11, catch-unit-test

I am trying to integrate `Catch` unit testing to my project but it fails for the currently available

```
Catch v1.10.0
Generated: 2017-08-26 15:16:46.676990
```

Example:

`test.cpp`

```
#include "catch.hpp"

#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN


TEST_CASE("CATCH TEST"){
    REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -std=c++11
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::endExpression(Catch::DecomposedExpression const&)", referenced from:
      Catch::BinaryExpression<int const&, (Catch::Internal::Operator)0, int const&>::endExpression() const in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::setResultType(bool)", referenced from:
      Catch::BinaryExpression<int const&, (Catch::Internal::Operator)0, int const&>::endExpression() const in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::useActiveException(Catch::ResultDisposition::Flags)", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::react()", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::ResultBuilder(char const*, Catch::SourceLineInfo const&, char const*, Catch::ResultDisposition::Flags, char const*)", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::~ResultBuilder()", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::SourceLineInfo::SourceLineInfo(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::isDebuggerActive()", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::AutoReg::AutoReg(void (*)(), Catch::SourceLineInfo const&, Catch::NameAndDesc const&)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::AutoReg::~AutoReg()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::toString(int)", referenced from:
      Catch::ExpressionLhs<int const&>::reconstructExpression(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) const in test-b77427.o
      Catch::BinaryExpression<int const&, (Catch::Internal::Operator)0, int const&>::reconstructExpression(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) const in test-b77427.o
  "Catch::ResultBuilder::shouldDebugBreak() const", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in test-b77427.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit
```

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: You have to link against that framework.

Comment: The framework claims it's header only https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md

Comment: You're right, sorry.  But `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` has to be before `#include "catch.hpp"`.

Comment: Yap, that was it.... It's counter intuitive to call a macro before including the library it's defined in? Thanks! :D

Comment: You should post it as the answer to collect some karma...

Comment: @ElDude think of it this way. In order for the library to see the define, the define has to come before it. It's pretty much a configuration parameter. If you wished you could also provide it by using a `-d` flag when building the program.

Comment: @PaulRooney not in that case -- `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` is used to generate Catch's definitions withing one of the user's .cpp files. Putting it into the compiler flags would create as many definitions as there are .cpp files including `catch.hpp`, violating the ODR.

Comment: @Quentin absolutely didn't think of that. I guess it would not be a good idea to use the compiler flag. Although no doubt the compiler would pull you up on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it stands your program does not have a `main` function.  If you compile it, the linker will complain about the absence of a main function.  Since you are writing unit tests using the catch framework, you want that framework to generate a `main` function for you.

The catch framework looks whether `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` is defined and if yes, it generates a `main` function for you which runs all the tests you define.  Because compilation is a linear process, the macro `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` has to be defined **before** including `catch.hpp`.  Otherwise, the library will never “see” this macro.

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("CATCH TEST"){
    REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PfFZgqTrlgk5AJQV)</kbd>

Comment: I have the same error as OP, but I have `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` at the top of the file

Comment: @AlexBuznik Is `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` the very first line of your file? If not, please try that.

Comment: Yes, it was the very first line. Anyway, the issue cleared when I included a locally-placed catch2 header file, rather than expecting for it from the CMake